# Auto increment by groups in SQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm loading csv files to sql, which follow the following structure:

```
d_1 = {'item':['a','b','c','d','e','f'],'group':['1','1','2','2','3','3']}
d_2 = {'item':['h','i','j','k'],'group':['1','2','3','4']}
```

Where the items have a name and a group number, which indicates if they form part of the same group. `Each these files will always start the group count on 1.`
What I want is to keep a counter on the database for the number of groups. The key here is that the counter must continue the count from the previous value, not starting again from 1.

The logic is as follows:
1) Upload the first file, I will have on the DB:

[image]

2) upload next file, I'll have:

[image]

Here the group count is the same that the one on the original files, butI want the counter to increment from the previous values:

[image]

So when I upload a new file, the count will start on 8.

Comment: `I'm loading csv files to sql` ... this looks like JSON to me.

Comment: I represent it as a dictionary, to not upload images.

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez, is it for one csv load, or do you want to keep track of the incremented # between csv loads to the SQL?

Comment: @ivan7707 I updated the question, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez, what I find confusing is this. Does the increment have anything to do with the actual group? Do you just want to find the highest previous group value and increment from there (has nothing specifically to do with the groups already in the DB)? a,b and h are in group 1, yet you start the increment at 4 for h.  This tells me the numbering has nothing to do with the group.

Comment: The way your 3rd df looks, it should simply be finding the max value of the group column prior to the new data load, then adding that number to the new group numbers, and inserting from there.

Comment: @ivan7707 The group number just means that those records are somehow related, I need to know that for further processing. Several people will be uploading this files independently so all the uploaded files will start the count at one, but on the database I don't wan't to mix the groups  so I need to increase the counter .